# How to set default encoding to utf-8, and default line ending to linux style?

Tags: character-encoding, newlines

I use this piece of code to set the default line ending to linux-style `\n`

```
;; https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EndOfLineTips

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'find-file-check-line-endings)

(defun dos-file-endings-p ()
  (string-match "dos" (symbol-name buffer-file-coding-system)))

(defun find-file-check-line-endings ()
  (when (dos-file-endings-p)
    (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'undecided-unix)
    (set-buffer-modified-p nil)))
```

And this - to set the default encoding to utf-8

```
;; emacs set default codepage

;; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785200/change-emacs-default-coding-system

(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8)
(setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8)
```

But it looks like because of the second one, first isn't working. Now line ending is `\r\n` on saving, even if I manually change it.

Comment: Could you clarify why you think you need to do anything at all?  If your locale uses utf-8 (which has been the default pretty much everywhere for the last 10 years, AFAIK), then Emacs will use utf-8 by default anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;; make unix lineendings default
(setq default-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
```

Answer (score 2):

For current release of emacs (26.1):

```
(setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
```

Verify with `C-h v buffer-file-coding-system`. It should say "global value is utf-8-unix".

Comment: What is the difference between `default-buffer-file-coding-system` and `buffer-file-coding-system`?